# Notation for permutation, use for summation indices.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, notation

Let

$$
\Sigma = \left\{ s_1,\ldots, s_n \right\}
$$

For fixed $1 \leq k \leq n$ there I have $\binom{n}{k}$ possible combination of substrings that don't count repetition and order,etc. Is there a way to denote the generic subset of $\Sigma$ having these $\binom{n}{k}$ elements?

The purpose would be to write as summation the following product

$$
f(\delta_1,\ldots,\delta_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+\delta_i)
$$

Following the comments:

Could be the following correct?

$$
f(\delta_1,...,\delta_n) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \sum_{\begin{array}{l} J \subset \cal{P}(\left\{1,...,n \right\}) \\ card \; J = k \end{array}}\delta_{J(1)} ...\delta_{J(k)}
$$

Comment: $\{E\subset\Sigma\;|\; \mathrm{Card} E=k\}$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I forgot a detail, would your suggestion change?

Comment: With $\Delta=\{\delta_1,\dots\delta_n\}$, $f(\delta_1,\dots\delta_n)=\sum_{E\subset\Delta}\prod_{k\in E} k$. Is that what you want? Here, you have to use the (usual) convention $\prod_{k\in\emptyset}k=1$.

Comment: My apologies, but I don't understand the notation. If you could elaborate a bit more with the meanings that would be helpful.

Comment: But I have the feeling that what you wrote is exactly what I'm after.

Comment: This simply means "the sum over all subsets of $\Delta$", and "the product over all elements of the chosen subset". That is, $k$ is any of the $\delta_i$ in $E$ ($k$ was a poor choice of variable name, as it's not an index, btw). To expand th sum, it's not useful to group the products by the size of $E$, but there are indeed $n \choose k$ subsets $E$ of $\Delta$ with exactly $k$ elements. I find it more clear to view this as a sum on any subset: pick $1$ or $\delta_i$ in each factor, this will give you $E$.

Comment: You last sum is not correct: for a given choice of indices, the product $\delta_{i_1}\dots\delta_{i_k}$ appears only once in the expanded product. Here you have a factor $n \choose k$ that can't be correct.

Comment: Any example you could provide me of how is such notation used?